# Jupyter / IPython markdown not working

Tags: ipython, markdown, jupyter-notebook

See https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQU9Z.png. The cell appears to be in markdown, but the latex doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you have to use two dollar sign `$$` and then it will work ... try that\
- So start with two dollar sign and end with two dollar sign
- See the image below:
  [image]
- It gives the following result[image]
- In you case `$$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$$`

  ### - You will get the following results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I just had to press the "run cell" button :P however, thanks for your answers.